# Dynamic filling 3D matrix from 2D matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a really short and easy question. This is what I'm dealing with:

```
  %% Load all samples 
nazwa = dir('*.asc');
temp = zeros(1,1);
A = zeros(1,1,1);

for i = 1:25
    filename = nazwa(i).name;
    temp = importfile(filename);
    A(:,:,i) = temp;
end
```

`temp` is a 4096x2 matrix, and I want to have a 4096x2x25 matrix `A` as a result. With this code I get a `Assignment has more non-singleton rhs dimensions than non-singleton subscripts`
 error. I know that I can use cells, or create bigger temp matrix, that would contain all the data at once and then convert it to 3D matrix, but I want to know what is wrong with my thinking. Is it indexing? I've found similar problem here: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/57275-adding-values-to-3d-matrix but that's not exactly for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general you can go changing a matrix size in a loop, but not the way you're doing it right now.

Why doesn't Matlab allow you?

Imagine the matrix `temp` changes size every iteration (you know it doesn't, but Matlab doesn't know) then what size would A be? How should matlab resize it?

Therefore, if you want to do what you are doing, you need to preallocate A. If you tell Matlab that `A=zeros(2096,2,25)`, then you won't have a problem.

Comment: +1 for you, ym friend, it did work. Could you tell me then what are the rules for changing matrix size in a loop? I did similar stuff before with prelocating matrixes just like here - with single zero matrix and I never had this kind of error.

Comment: "similar stuff"? Like what? In general, if you want to access something like A(:,N) then A should be preallocated.

Comment: `Yssmini = zeros(1,1);     Yssmin = zeros(1,1);   for i=1:size(GROOVES_VALUES,2) %finds exact index of minimas in each column of Yss   Yssmin(1,i) = min(Yss3d(:,1,i));   j = find(Yss3d(:,:,i) == Yssmin(1,i));   Yssmini(1,i) = j;   end` Here for example - I have prellocated Yssmin with one-by-one matrix, and the code still works.

Comment: I don't think that Matlab has problem with A(:,N) without preallocting, even without `A=zeros(1,1,1);`, so the code of `Yssmin` suppose to work also without the preallocate. Maybe in the code of the question, `temp` is really has different sizes in different iterations

Comment: @KrystianMeresiński As far as I see you are not asssinging any variable to something, like in  A(:,n)=B , but you are accessing the matrix, like in    B= A(:,N).